# Entity Framework 6 to add one-to-one association between a SalesOrder.CustomerID and Customer.Id

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity

To everyone,

I'm trying to instantiate a SalesOrder Customer object so I can add the Customer's DisplayName to the SalesOrder.

I have this code in the SalesOrder class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

#nullable disable

namespace DataLayer
{
    public partial class SalesOrder
    {
        public SalesOrder()
        {
            this.SalesOrderLineItems = new HashSet<SalesOrderLineItem>();

            //this.Customer = new Customer().;         

        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderLineItem> SalesOrderLineItems { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The SalesOrder does retrieve the SalesOrderLineItems. However, everything I try to fill  the instance of the Customer fails. I have the CustomerID FK on the SalesOrder object. I'm trying to use that PK/FK reference to the Customer row to bring in the instance of the customer which will allow me to reach the cust.DisplayName property. Just as I have with the SalesOrder.SalesOrderLineItems I want the Customer object to be properly attached to the SalesOrder object.

Here is the table structure which is normal PK/FK configuration between SalesOrder.CustomerID FK and Customer.Id PK.

Here is the code in the API controller that loads the SalesOrderLineItems to the SalesOrder object. This is all working perfectly...I think.

```
        public JsonResult GetSalesOrderByID(Guid salesorderid)
        {
            {
                
                var context = db.Set<SalesOrder>();
                SalesOrder sorder = context.First(s => s.Id == salesorderid);
                context.Entry(sorder).Collection(l => l.SalesOrderLineItems).Load();

                return new JsonResult(sorder);
            }
        }
```

```
USE [Backend]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[**SalesOrder**]    Script Date: 12/16/2022 9:20:54 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesOrder](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SalesOrder] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SalesOrder_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SalesOrder]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SalesOrder_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SalesOrder] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SalesOrder_Customer]
GO
```

```
USE [Backend]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customer]    Script Date: 12/16/2022 9:29:17 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]
GO
```

Here is the JSON response as of now:

```
{
   "id": "fea1996f-7569-4556-971c-ecb125a53b53",
   "date": "2022-10-30T00:00:00",
   "customerID": "23a85521-d834-47b9-be0a-2d34fde6c2dc",
   "salesOrderLineItems":    [
            {
         "id": "7ca18a2d-1c3c-4ab6-a583-aafe3342f3d2",
         "salesOrderID": "fea1996f-7569-4556-971c-ecb125a53b53",
         "productID": "a8ee410e-aba3-45dc-aec3-5be389d98f96",
         "productDisplayName": "Acme Soap",
         "quantity": 30,
         "price": 200
      },
            {
         "id": "286997cc-b552-44fd-b7dc-fb60cfe88b61",
         "salesOrderID": "fea1996f-7569-4556-971c-ecb125a53b53",
         "productID": "0c56a53a-25c2-4ebf-a859-591edefb2657",
         "productDisplayName": "Central Widget",
         "quantity": 200,
         "price": 1.05
      }
   ],
   "customer": null
}
```

The ideal response would be:

```
{
   "id": "fea1996f-7569-4556-971c-ecb125a53b53",
   "date": "2022-10-30T00:00:00",
   "customerID": "23a85521-d834-47b9-be0a-2d34fde6c2dc",
   "CustomerDisplayName": "Jack Doe",
   "salesOrderLineItems":    [
            {
         "id": "7ca18a2d-1c3c-4ab6-a583-aafe3342f3d2",
         "salesOrderID": "fea1996f-7569-4556-971c-ecb125a53b53",
         "productID": "a8ee410e-aba3-45dc-aec3-5be389d98f96",
         "productDisplayName": "Acme Soap",
         "quantity": 30,
         "price": 200
      },
            {
         "id": "286997cc-b552-44fd-b7dc-fb60cfe88b61",
         "salesOrderID": "fea1996f-7569-4556-971c-ecb125a53b53",
         "productID": "0c56a53a-25c2-4ebf-a859-591edefb2657",
         "productDisplayName": "Central Widget",
         "quantity": 200,
         "price": 1.05
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to populate the full customer object to start with but that might not be necessary.

Ideally I'd just like the Customer.Display name to be added as a property of the SalesOrder. Then I wouldn't need the entire Customer object which is not necessary.

So maybe SalesOrder looks like this with just the CustomerDisplayName added. But I still need to reach the related Customer to derive the CustomerDisplayName.

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    public partial class SalesOrder
    {
        public SalesOrder()
        {
            this.SalesOrderLineItems = new HashSet<SalesOrderLineItem>();

            //this.Customer = new Customer().;         

        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderLineItem> SalesOrderLineItems { get; set; }
        public virtual string CustomerDisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help in advance,
E

I tried to decorate the SalesOrder with the
[ForeignKey] attribute and define the CustomerID, but that didn't work.

I tried to load the Customer collection as I did with the SalesOrderLineItems, but of course the Customer doesn't have the SalesOrder relationship as the SalesOrderLineItem does. The Customer stands alone by itself and is referenced/associated in SalesOrder as a FK.

Comment: I was able to load the customer via this .Load statement being added to the controller.         public JsonResult GetSalesOrderByID(Guid salesorderid)
        {
            {                
                var context = db.Set<SalesOrder>();
                SalesOrder sorder = context.First(s => s.Id == salesorderid);
                context.Entry(sorder).Collection(l => l.SalesOrderLineItems).Load();
                context.Entry(sorder).Reference(c => c.Customer).Load();

                return new JsonResult(sorder);
            }
        }

Comment: How does everyone suggest to remove the CustomerID from the base SalesOrder so its duplicate value is not returned in the response.